# How do I center the content of a zoomed UIWebView page?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am developing an iPhone Application and I am trying to center the following webpage: https://ls.betradar.com/ls/livescore/?/betitbest/de/page/sportcenter_single#matchid_4768166

in a UIWebView. Now this normally wouldn't be a problem, but I am zooming into the page with a factor of 2.2, in order to span the content from edge to edge.

Unfortunately while setting the zoom factor works correctly, the content is not displayed in the center.

Can anybody help me? i attach the code I use while loading the view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _urlOfLiveMatchView = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ls.betradar.com/ls/livescore/?/betitbest/de/page/sportcenter_single#matchid_4768166"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_urlOfLiveMatchView];
    [_matchAppView loadRequest:requestObj];
    _matchAppView.scrollView.zoomScale = 2.2;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry I just posted it.